# bulk PHP isset generator

Tags: php, isset

I just joined a project developed in plain php ( As in no frameworks). I have a table that has 213 fields and according to the guidelines i have to do an isset, prepare string, prepare number for 212 fields.

This is a lot of repetitive code and most of the tables in this system are huge. As such i would like to save time by developing an isset generator but before I go re-inventing the wheel i would like to ask: Can anyone point me in the direction of such a generator that returns the isset code? Something similar to http://www.fpmgonline.com/mysql_insert.php

---

### Edited to add code

Supposing $data is my $_POST array , instead of checking many fields one by one I wanted to generate a bulk isset code

Here's is some sample code

```
<?php
$data = Array('name' => 'Sample name', 'desc' => 'Sample description');

if (isset($data['name'])) {
    $name = trim($data['name']);
} else {
    $return[] = ' Name code is required';
}

if (isset($data['desc'])) {
    $desc = trim($data['desc']);
} else {
    $return[] = ' Description is name is required';
}

if (isset($data['age'])) {
    $age = trim($data['age']);
} else {
    $age = 0;
}
?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Show your code, it's hard to imagine your situation

Comment: this is why we use programming languages :P

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for "generating" code. That's why you have data structures, loops and conditionals in programming languages.

```
$data = Array('name' => 'Sample name', 'desc' => 'Sample description', 'age' => 'Foo bar');
$defaults = Array('age' => 0);
$messages = Array('name' => ' Name code is required', 'desc' => ' Description is name is required');

for($data as $key => $val) {
    if (isset($data[$key])) {
        $$key = trim($data[$key]);
    } else if (isset($defaults[$key])) {
        $$key = $defaults[$key];
    } else {
        $return[] = $messages[$key];
    }
}
```

The need to use variable variables (`$$key`) here also is plain wrong. When working with "dynamic" data you should not need to work with a separate variable for each item. I'd refactor that into this:

```
$clean_data = Array();

for($data as $key => $val) {
    if (isset($data[$key])) {
        $clean_data[$key] = trim($data[$key]);
    } else if (isset($defaults[$key])) {
        $clean_data[$key] = $defaults[$key];
    } else {
        $return[] = $messages[$key];
    }
}
```

Also `$data` should not be whatever comes from `$_POST`. It should be everything that's in your fields list and then check if it's present in `$_POST`, so that **you don't end up running arbitrary code based on user input**.

Comment: I like your solution but like i said, I don't have much leeway here and I have to follow their strict guidelines ( I am told  for ease of maintainance). But i'll use you logic for my function

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution and the heads -up on the field lists.

Answer (score 0):

I did a simple one for the isset:

```
$data = Array('name' => 'Sample name', 'desc' => 'Sample description');

bulkisset($data, 'name,description,age');

function bulkisset($data, $table_fields) {
    $code = '';
    $inputs = explode(',', $table_fields);
    foreach ($inputs as $key) {
        $code .= '<br/>if (isset($data["' . $key . '"])){'
                . '$name = trim($data["' . $key . '"]);} else {$' . $key . ' ="";};';
    }
    echo $code;
}
```

This might not be the best way to check data but with my hands tied I think this will save me some time.